# primStringEquality not reducing

Tags: agda

When asking Agda to normalize `test` on the following program:

```
data Bool : Set where
  T : Bool
  F : Bool
{-# BUILTIN BOOL  Bool  #-}
{-# BUILTIN TRUE  T #-}
{-# BUILTIN FALSE F #-}

postulate String : Set
postulate primStringEquality : String → String → Bool
{-# BUILTIN STRING String #-}

test : Bool
test = primStringEquality "bar" "foo"
```

It returns `primStringEquality "bar" "foo"` instead of `F`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `primitive` for equality instead of `postulate`. We also have to declare `BUILTIN STRING` before the primitives.

```
postulate String : Set
{-# BUILTIN STRING String #-}

primitive primStringEquality : String → String → Bool
```

Comment: Thanks. We have a documentation bug [here](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/built-ins.html#booleans) then. Should I report on agda's main repo?

Comment: @MaiaVictor yeah that'd be helpful.